# How do I resolve Syntax error: Unexpected token (100:33) in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Issue:
The below link shows the problem I have while I was coding, could someone help me how to solve it?

[My Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S256m.png)

My Code:

```js
            <Modal
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
                aria-describedby="simple-modal-description">
                <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
                    <p>Select files you want to upload!</p>
                    {
                        uploading ? (
                            <p>Uploading...</p>
                        ) : (   
                                <> 
                                   <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
                                   <button onClick={handleUpload}>Upload</button> 
                                </>
                            )
                    }
                </div>
            </Modal>
```

Comment: Could someone please help me? You can ask questions if you don't understand my question but please help me.. this means a lot to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think just replacing `<>` with `<div>` will fix the issue

```
        <Modal
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
            aria-describedby="simple-modal-description">
            <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
                <p>Select files you want to upload!</p>
                {
                    uploading ? (
                        <p>Uploading...</p>
                    ) : (   
                            <div> 
                               <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
                               <button onClick={handleUpload}>Upload</button> 
                            <div/>
                        )
                }
            </div>
        </Modal>
```